# How to preserve UVs when using Decimate?

Tags: uv, modifiers, three.js

I have a few meshes in which I load into Three.js using the `JSONLoader`. The problem is, the huge JSON files take up too much memory so I need to reduce the amount of polys in my meshes. Currently, they are sitting at ~84,000, ~103,000, and ~178,200 vertices.

I tried using the Decimate modifer to un-subdivide, but have had no luck as the UVs become ruined, and thus my textures are also ruined. I don't have time to fully retopologize or make a lower poly mesh. I searched and found the poly-reducer script, but it was removed in 2.49. What other options do I have to reduce the poly count and allow my mesh to work with Three.js?

Comment: Try decimate planar with delimit UV option enabled

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To keep UVs with Decimate Modifier you need to use **Planar** dissolve and enable **UVs** in Delimit section of Decimate modifier

[image]